# Prove that every element of $V$ can be expressed as $w+cv_0$ for some $w\in \ker(T)$ and $c\in \mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and let $T:V\to \mathbb R$ a linear transformation. Suppose $\ker(T)\neq V$ and let $v_0\in V$ so that $v_0\notin \ker(T)$. Prove that every element of $V$ can be expressed as $w+cv_0$ for some $w\in \ker(T)$ and $c\in \mathbb R$

We know that $\dim(\mathbb R)$ over $\mathbb R$ is $1$ so $T(v_0)$ is a basis of $\mathbb R$:  $T(v)=cT(v_0)$ for some $c\in \mathbb R$; $w\in \ker (T)$ so $T(w)=0$ therefore $T(v)=cT(v_0)+T(w)=T(cv_0+w)$ but I don´t know how to conclude that $v=cv_0+w$

Can you give me a hand please? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Your $w$ is not chosen in any particular way; you cannot expect $v=cv_0+w$ to hold for _every_ $w\in\ker(T)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to go from here: You have written $T(v) = T(c v_0 + w)$, but really since, as you have observed, $T(w) = 0$ you could just as well write $T(v) = T(c v_0)$.  What does this say about $v - c v_0$?

Comment: $v-cv_0\in ker(T)$ then $v-cv_0=w+cv_0-cv_0=w\in ker(T)$ for some $w$, is this correct?

Comment: Echoing Marc's comment that $w$ depends on $v$.  If $v - c v_0 = w$ and $w \in Ker(T)$ then I think you have what you want!